# Executing a Dynamic query having sys objects using Execute Immediate twice

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have a string that is saving a query dynamically from a procedure call.
The query is selecting data from SYS objects like dba_*

I am not able to open the query using execute immediate or Open cursor when calling the string using execute immediate. Any Options to enable this as I cannot get grants on sys objects from DBA to the schema.

Below is an example of how two execute immediate statements are getting used in my code to access the SYS object.

```
create or replace procedure exp_11 authid current_user as
v_query1 varchar2(100):='select count(1) from dba_objects';
v_query2 varchar2(100):='execute immediate TXT';
v_res number;
v_txt varchar2(100);
begin
v_txt:='select count(1) from dba_objects';
execute immediate v_query1 into v_res;
dbms_output.put_line(v_res);
--This will work with execute immediate directly calling the select statement from dba_objects

v_query2:=replace(v_query2,'TXT',v_txt);
execute immediate v_query2 into v_res;
--This will not work
dbms_output.put_line(v_res);
end;
/
```

Comment: mysql or oracle? I dont think you should include both tags

Comment: Define "not able".  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?  It sounds like you are saying that you don't have permissions to query those objects and your DBA won't grant you permissions to query those objects.  If that's the case, you can't query those objects.

Comment: I can select from dba_objects when using a single execute immediate when i define procedure with authid current_user. My requirement is to dynamically define queries (like v_query2). If this has data dictionary tables, then I cannot use execute immediate twice in them. I cannot open a cursor also on a query that uses dba_* tables. So needed an alternative

Answer (score 1):

*authid current_user*  is used to execute the procedure with the privileges of the current user (instead of using privileges of user that created the procedure), so if the user you are using does not have SELECT rights (or other needed permissions) on DBA tables, there is no way how to make it work.

If possible, you can make this procedure in a schema that is owned by user that has these rights (like SYS) and mae it without "authid current_user", make public synonym for procedure and grant execute rights to users that need it. This way procedure will have access to whatever it's schema owner has and users executing procedure won't have permission issues.

That said, if the first part with *v_query1* works, and you can execute it, it's not a question of permissions. With or without *execute immediate*, permissions work the same. Your procedure is not working because this line isn't correct:

```
v_query2:=replace(v_query2,'TXT',v_txt);
```

You are replacing 'TXT' in query:

```
'execute immediate TXT';
```

With v_txt:

```
v_txt:='select count(1) from dba_objects';
```

So your SQL statement eventually is:

```
execute immediate 'execute immediate select count(1) from dba_objects' into v_res;
```

And that is invalid. You can't use execute immediate twice! (See more about syntax [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm#i33888)).

You said that you need to dynamically define queries, but why do you need to put 'execute immediate' in them? Why just not define them without it?

```
create or replace procedure exp_11 authid current_user as
    v_query2 varchar2(100);
begin
    v_query2 :='select count(1) from dba_objects';
    execute immediate v_query2 into v_res;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_res);
end;
/
```